# Java - Objective C - for each loop issue

Tags: java, objective-c, foreach

I'm trying to build an application in Android using some codes from Objective-C (IPhone app).I'm trying to understand what exactly is doing a piece of code and translate it into Java code,but I think I need a little help here.So first, here is the Obj-C code :

```
  (BOOL)processSqlInjectQueries:(NSArray *)injectQueries error:(NSError**)error {
    //some code

    for(NSDictionary * q in injectQueries)
                {
                    if (![q isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) continue;

                    StPacketInjectQueryPackage qType  = (StPacketInjectQueryPackage)[[q objectForKey:@"type"] intValue];
                    NSString * query = [q objectForKey:@"query"];
                }
    //some code
    }
```

In Java, I'm trying to do something like this :

```
         // in some other method :

        JSONObject jsonData= new JSONObject();
        String authHash = jsonData.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash").toString();
        List<Map<String,String>> injectQueries= new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        injectQueries.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
        //injectQueries.add(authHash);


    public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(List<Map<String,String>> injectQueries, Exception error){

        if(injectQueries==null || injectQueries.size()==0){
            boolean injectsProcessed = this.processSqlInjectQueries(injectQueries,error);
            if(!injectsProcessed){
                return false;
            }
        }

        Log.i("Info","Processing INJECT Queries...");
        boolean res = true;
        /*[_dbAdapter beginTransaction];
        [_user.userDbAdapter beginTransaction];*/

        for(Map<String,String> b : injectQueries){

            if(b.getClass().getName()!=injectQueries.getClass().getName()){
                continue;
            }
            //RPCPacketInjectQueryPackage qType = (RPCPacketInjectQueryPackage) 
        }

        return true;
    }
```

But my problem is that is that I get this error : `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to ArrayList`.

Any suggestion how to fix that error?

And second question : Can I use `Exception error` in declaraion of `processSqlInjectQueries` instead of `NSError *error` in Obj-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective C code is passing through an NSArray containing NSDictionaries through to the method, so the following is probably closer to what you want to do...

```
public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(List<Map<String,String> injectQueries) {
    for(Map<String,String> q : injectQueries) {
        // do stuff with q
    }
}
```

To handle the error code, you probably want to think about throwing an exception rather than trying to pass through an "Error" object, so something like the following:

```
public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(List<Map<String,String> injectQueries) throws Exception {
    for(Map<String,String> q : injectQueries) {
        // do stuff with q
    }

    if(errorConditionOccurs) {
       throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

You'll want to tailor the exact Exception that's thrown so it matches whatever your code is trying to do.

**In response to comment**: perhaps this is closer to what you're trying to do?

```
public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    for(String key : jsonObject.keys()) {
        Object value = jsonOnject.get(key);
        // Do stuff with value
    }
    // Do more stuff
}
```

And you could call it with:

```
processSqlInjectQueries(jsonData.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash"));
```

Comment: What if I try to add this : ***String queries = jsonData.getJSONObject("client_auth_hash").toString();*** to injectQueries. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Comment: Not totally sure what you're asking, but if your data's in a JSON Object you could adjust your method to take a JSONObject instead of the List<Map> structure.  You could the loop through the keys of your jsonObject to get at the different values.

Comment: @Android-Droid I've added a further suggestion to my answer which is perhaps closer to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually your answer really helped me to understand what to do! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So the for each part is done, but now I have another problem...How can I translate this code : ***StPacketInjectQueryPackage qType  = (StPacketInjectQueryPackage)[[q objectForKey:@"type"] intValue];*** // StPacketInjectQueryPackage is enum type.

Comment: @Andriod-Droid, I think we'd need more information about what you've done so far, and what your code is meant to be doing to answer.  Perhaps you should post a new question?

Comment: I just update my question with the code I'm using..and my only problem it that I'm trying to convert this line : ***StPacketInjectQueryPackage qType = (StPacketInjectQueryPackage)[[q objectForKey:@"type"] intValue];*** Which I can't really understand how it's work.

Answer (score 7):

**Iterating over the ArrayList**

The error is being raised because your code needs to declare that `b` is an `Object` (since `injectQueries` contains objects of type `Object`, not objects of type `ArrayList`):

```
for(Object b : injectQueries){
    ...
}
```

Since the `NSDictionary` class in Objective-C closely resembles the `Map` class in Java, you can mimic the Objective-C code by casting `b` as a `Map`, or even better, you can use generics to specify that `injectQueries` contains `Map` objects.  For example:

```
public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(List<Map<String,String> injectQueries, Exception error) {

    // some code

    for(Map<String,String> b : injectQueries) {
        ...
    }

    // some code
    return true;
}
```

**Exception Handling**

As for your second question, methods in Java normally communicate error conditions by throwing `Exception` objects, so your method signature would resemble the following:

```
public boolean processSqlInjectQueries(List<Map<String,String> injectQueries) throws Exception
```

Note that it's always better to be specific with your exceptions (i.e. to throw objects that are subclasses of `Exception`) so that your method caller has some idea of what went wrong.  See the following link for additional guidelines for handling exceptions in Java:

http://www.javapractices.com/home/HomeAction.do#Exceptions