# Java for each issue

Tags: java, android, foreach

Actually I was searching for an example or similar question in Stackoverflow and I find this one : [Java Objective-C for each issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270669/java-objective-c-for-each-loop-issue). So that's why I'll give the code which Android-Droid is using in his example.The thing that I need to do is similar to the Objective C code that he is using :

`StPacketInjectQueryPackage qType  = (StPacketInjectQueryPackage)[[q objectForKey:@"type"] intValue];` .

According to his code...my question is how can I do that...using his Java code?

**EDIT (My Problem):**

If I use his code, how can I get the objectForKey:@"type" in Java.I guess it has to be similar to this :

```
        RPCPacketInjectQueryPackage qType = (RPCPacketInjectQueryPackage) b.getKeys
```

OR `b.get("type");`  or something like that...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For-each in Java is pretty well documented in the standard Java documentation.  For example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

If that doesn't adequately explain how to do what you're trying to do, I would suggest taking  a stab at it in Java and then asking a question on StackOverflow about what is wrong with your code if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I just update my question with the problem that I want to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing in Java is a new (1.5 or 1.6) "enhanced" `for` loop.

```
  Iterable<Element> list = ....
  for (Element el : list) {
      System.out.println(el);
  }
```

Comment: Its not exactly foreach but enhanced for loop. Works exactly like that but instead of foreach use for.

Comment: And about Element...what is it actually? Cuz there is two different kind of imports for it.Which one I have to use?

Comment: @Bombastic I put Element as an example, you use your own class instead of it (`Iterable<Object>`, `Iterable<String>`...). Also, Iterable is an interface that the container must implement, usually you will be using a List or Set implementation.